# Tengo este Error usando ts en react y nextUI 2.0 en el componente Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, ts

Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set>>' is not assignable to type '(keys: Selection) => any'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'keys' are incompatible.
Type 'Selection' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Set>'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Set>'

este es el codigo el error esta en la linea 184 y no me deja compilar por el error de arriba ya he buscado pero no encuentro nada

```javascript
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, DropdownTrigger, Image } from '@nextui-org/react'
import { PostFormbar } from '../bars/PostFormbar'
import categoriesData from '../../assets/categories.json'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { IconMinus } from '../icons/MinusIcon'
import Markdown from 'react-markdown'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkGemoji from 'remark-gemoji'
import { useAddPost } from '../../store/useAddPost'
import moment from 'moment'

function UploadFeaturedImg({ setImg, setImgFile }: { setImg: any; setImgFile: any }) {
  const [isImg, setIsImg] = useState(null)
  const caption = useAddPost((state) => state.caption)
  const setCaption = useAddPost((state) => state.setCaption)

  const getImg = (ev) => {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
      // Usar la interfaz DataTransferItemList para acceder a el/los archivos)
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        // Si los elementos arrastrados no son ficheros, rechazarlos
        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
          const file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile()

          setIsImg(file.path)
          setImgFile({ imgFile: file })
          setImg({ img: file.name })
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Usar la interfaz DataTransfer para acceder a el/los archivos
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
        console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name)
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className='w-full h-screen hover:bg-blue-500'
        onDragOver={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation()
          event.preventDefault()
        }}
      >
        <div className='w-full h-full' onDrop={getImg}>
          {isImg && (
            <div className='w-full h-screen'>
              <Image src={isImg} className='w-screen h-screen object-cover rounded-none' />
              <CaptionInput caption={caption} setCaption={setCaption} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export function CaptionInput({ caption, setCaption }: { caption: string; setCaption: any }) {
  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      className='absolute right-5 bottom-[-15%] z-10 outline-none bg-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md'
      value={caption}
      onChange={(event) => setCaption({ caption: event.target.value })}
    />
  )
}

export function TitleInput({ title, setTitle }: { title: string; setTitle: any }) {
  return (
    <textarea
      placeholder='Titulo'
      className='w-full outline-none text-4xl font-bold mt-2 hover:shadow-lg rounded-lg p-2'
      value={title}
      onChange={(event) => setTitle({ title: event.target.value })}
    />
  )
}
export function LeadInput({ lead, setLead }: { lead: string; setLead: any }) {
  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder='Sumario'
      className='w-full outline-none font-medium italic mt-2 hover:shadow-lg rounded-lg p-2'
      value={lead}
      onChange={(event) => setLead({ lead: event.target.value })}
    />
  )
}

export function AuthorInput({ author, setAuthor }: { author: string; setAuthor: any }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}')

    setAuthor({ author: `${user?.name} ${user?.lastname}` })
  }, [])

  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder='Author'
      className='w-full font-bold text-gray-600 outline-none hover:shadow-lg rounded-lg pl-2'
      value={author}
      onChange={(event) => setAuthor({ author: event.target.value })}
    />
  )
}

function setCurrentDate() {
  moment.locale('es')
  const setDate = moment().format('l')
  const setHour = moment().format('H')
  const setMinute = moment().format('mm')

  const newDate = `${setDate} · ${setHour}:${setMinute} UTC-4`
  return newDate
}

export function DateInput({ date, setDate }: { date: string; setDate: any }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setDate({ date: setCurrentDate() })
  }, [])

  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder='Fecha'
      className='w-full text-lg outline-none hover:shadow-lg rounded-lg pl-2'
      value={date}
      onChange={(event) => setDate({ date: event.target.value })}
    />
  )
}

export function BodyInput({ body, setBody }: { body: string; setBody: any }) {
  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        placeholder='Body'
        className='w-full p-2 outline-none mt-2 hover:shadow-lg rounded-lg'
        onChange={(event) => setBody({ body: event.target.value })}
        value={body}
      />
      <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm, remarkGemoji]} className='prose'>
        {body}
      </Markdown>
    </>
  )
}

export function CategoriesDropdown({
  categories,
  setCategories
}: {
  categories: string[]
  setCategories: any
}) {
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set(['Categorias']))

  useEffect(() => {
    Array.from(selectedKeys).join(', ').replaceAll('_', ' '), [selectedKeys]
    setCategories({ categories: Array.from(selectedKeys)[0] })
    console.log(categories)
  }, [selectedKeys])

  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown>
        <DropdownTrigger className='flex flex-row items-center'>
          <p>
            {<IconMinus className='text-red-700 text-3xl' />}{' '}
            {selectedKeys ? selectedKeys : 'Categorias'}
          </p>
        </DropdownTrigger>
        <DropdownMenu
          aria-label='Static Actions'
          closeOnSelect={false}
          disallowEmptySelection
          selectionMode='single'
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          onSelectionChange={setSelectedKeys}
        >
          {categoriesData.map((categorie) => {
            return <DropdownItem key={categorie.title}>{categorie.title}</DropdownItem>
          })}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </>
  )
}

export function PostForm() {
  const title = useAddPost((state) => state.title)
  const setTitle = useAddPost((state) => state.setTitle)
  const lead = useAddPost((state) => state.lead)
  const setLead = useAddPost((state) => state.setLead)
  const author = useAddPost((state) => state.author)
  const setAuthor = useAddPost((state) => state.setAuthor)
  const date = useAddPost((state) => state.date)
  const setDate = useAddPost((state) => state.setDate)
  const body = useAddPost((state) => state.body)
  const setBody = useAddPost((state) => state.setBody)
  const categories = useAddPost((state) => state.categories)
  const setCategories = useAddPost((state) => state.setCategories)
  const setImg = useAddPost((state) => state.setImg)
  const setImgFile = useAddPost((state) => state.setImgFile)

  return (
    <>
      <PostFormbar />
      <UploadFeaturedImg setImg={setImg} setImgFile={setImgFile} />

      <div className='grid grid-cols-8 gap-2 mb-80'>
        <div className='col-span-2 flex flex-col justify-start items-center p-4'>
          <CategoriesDropdown categories={categories} setCategories={setCategories} />
        </div>
        <div className='col-span-6 pr-4 gap-2'>
          <TitleInput title={title} setTitle={setTitle} />
          <LeadInput lead={lead} setLead={setLead} />
          <div className='mt-2 mb-2'>
            <AuthorInput author={author} setAuthor={setAuthor} />
            <DateInput date={date} setDate={setDate} />
          </div>
          <div className='w-full bg-black h-[1px]' />

          <BodyInput body={body} setBody={setBody} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Estoy usando reactjs con ts y la libreria nextUI 2.0 [nextUI](https://nextui.org/docs/components/dropdown)
pienso que talvez pueda deshabilitar eso pero no se si se pueda y nose de que forma tiparlo para que no me de el error